# Problem creating proxy class with wsdl.exe

Tags: .net, web-services, proxy-classes, sap-crm

I need to create a .net client which consumes a webservice from a SAP CRM application. I just got the WSDL file. But when I try to create a proxy class with wsdl.exe I get a warning that no classes are generated. What am I doing wrong?

There is the header of the WSDL file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:n1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks

EDIT:
The error message I get is in german.

> ```
> Die SOAP 1.1-Bindung wurde nicht gefunden.: WS-I Basic Profile, Version
> ```
>
> 1.1, umf
> asst Implementierungsrichtlinien, in denen Verfahren zur Verwendung
> einer Gruppe
> wichtiger Webdienstspezifikationen zum
> Entwickeln von interoperablen
> Webdienste
> n empfohlen werden. Für das 1.1-Profil lauten diese Spezifikationen SOAP 1.1, WS
> DL 1.1, UDDI 2.0, XML 1.0 und XML Schema.
>
> ```
> Weitere Informationen zu WS-I Basic Profile Version 1.1 finden Sie
> ```
>
> in der Spezif
> ikation unter
> http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html.
>
> ```
> Warnung: Es wurden keine Klassen generiert.
> Warnungen. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in den generierten
> ```
>
> Quellkommentaren.

It says that the SOAP 1.1 Binding was not found.

UPDATE: I just used svcutil.exe to create proxy classes and it worked. But how do I now configure the proxy class to the right end point?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: can you show us the bottom of the wsdl file?
there will be the soap:address and the wsdl:port tags which is what you need.

Comment: hi
there is no <wsdl:port> element in that wsdl document. just <wsdl:portType>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used svcutil instead of wsdl and it worked.
cheers

update:
using of svcutil was not enough. sap can provide many kinds of wsdl. but only the full wsdl (incl. port and binding) did it.
otherwise you just get an xstream error.

thanks flurin for your hint!