# Configuration of webservice client

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2008, sap-crm

I've created proxy classes using svcutil with a given "SAP CRM" WSDL file. It worked great and it generated a output.cs.

So added this output.cs in my visual studio project und created a simple test application. The test application can be compiled and even run, but I don't know why. I didn't enter any service URL.

How can this be and how can I configure the test application to use the proper SAP URL?

Thanks

it's a follow up question to this [Problem creating proxy class with wsdl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108349/problem-creating-proxy-class-with-wsdl-exe)

Comment: What specifically you want to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have following constructors in your generated proxy:

```
 public SampleServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName)
        :
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

public SampleServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
    :
        base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
```

The first one references [endpoint description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731762.aspx) in your config file, the other accepts programmatically created binding and endpoint address.

As for username/password part, with your binding properly configured, use the proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName property.

Answer (score 0):

in the ouput.cs file check the constructor, URL is propably appended in it. Change the default constructor to accept URL as parameter and assign the given URL ..

Comment: This way you'll need to re-edit your code every time you run svcutil